# Im trying to build a basic math game using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is all my code I hope you can see where I'm going wrong.

```
           var $randomnumber1;
            var $randomnumber2;
            var $answer;            
            var $counter = 1;
            var $data;
    function start_game() { 
         document.getElementById('counternumber').innerHTML = $counter; 
         document.getElementById('txtbox').value = "";                  
         $randomnumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);                 

            document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = $randomnumber1; 
                $answer = $randomnumber1 + $randomnumber2;
                $counter++; 
                setFocus();                 
    }           
    function check_answer() {
            var $txt = document.getElementById('txtbox'); 
            var $value = $txt.value;
                if ($value == $answer) {
                    alert('You are correct');
                }
                else {
                    alert('You are incorrect, the answer was ' + $answer);
                }
            document.getElementById('txtbox').value = "";               
            document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML = ""; 
                     $randomnumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*11); 
                     $randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
                     document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = $randomnumber1; 
                     document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML = $randomnumber2;

                        $answer = $randomnumber1 + $randomnumber2;
                document.getElementById('counternumber').innerHTML = $counter;
                $counter++; 
                    if ($counter > 4) {
                        alert ('End of game......Thanks for playing');
                        $counter = 1;
                            document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = "";
                            document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML = ""; 
                    }
```

function addAnswers() {
            var data = $randomnumber1 + " + " + $randomnumber2 + " = " + ($randomnumber1+$randomnumber2)
            var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
            var newText = document.createTextNode(data);
                    newListItem.appendChild(newText);
                    document.getElementById("ans").appendChild(newListItem);
        }

```
        <div class="container" id="wrapper">
        <h3>Games Played = <b id='counternumber'></b> / 3 </h3>
        <div id="total">Total: <p id="sumtotal"></p></div>

            <div class="left"><h3 id="num1"></h3></div>
            <div class="plus"><img src="images/plus.png"></div>
            <div class="right"><h3 id="num2"></h3></div>


        <button onclick="start_game(); myCountDown()">Start Game</button>

            <form id="form">
                 <input type="text" id="txtbox" /> 
                 <input type="button" value="Answer" onclick="check_answer(); setFocus(); ShowResults(); sumResults()" />
            </form> 
        </div>
    <a href="index.html">home page</a>

    </div> <!-- /content -->

    <div id="aside">

    </div>
```

Comment: You haven't stated your question.

Comment: Show us your tries. Does it work already?

Comment: @gordon falvey, check the following link: https://www.theharnishes.com/math24.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
        function addAnswers()
        {
            var data = $randomnumber1 + " + " + $randomnumber2 + " = " + ($randomnumber1+$randomnumber2)
            var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
            var newText = document.createTextNode(data);
            newListItem.appendChild(newText);
            document.getElementById("ans").appendChild(newListItem);
        }
```

Your question is unclear, but this should be something along the lines of what you're looking for. What you have to do is add a `<ul>` with the id of `ans` and this function will append `li` components to it (your answers) every time you run it. The answer itself will be stored into `data`.

Try it - if you want help customizing it, please update your answer.

Comment: thanks so much for the help but i must have an error somewhere as i cannot get the function addanswers to display.

Comment: I have created the ul as you said but the function will still not run. could you please have a look at my code as im new to javascript and I cannot see where the error is.

Comment: @gordon, post your code and I will try, or send me a private message.

Comment: You might have to change the function to fit your variables a little bit, I made it and tested it but I obviously can't know if the variables are identical to the ones you have used.

Comment: is it possible to Private message on this site. Im having a bit of trouble trying to post my javascript and HTML. is there an easier way to post the code

Comment: When I was loading my code to the site I deleted the random number generator code and document.getelementbyid code from the start function by accident